# Magento 2: Override XML file from vendor folder to app folder doesn't work/update

Tags: magento2, layout, overrides, xml

I tried to override the XML file by copying the file from

> vendor/magento/module-catalog/view/frontend/layout/catalog_category_view_type_default.xml

**to**

> app/design/frontend/Infortis/base/Magento_Catalog/layout/catalog_category_view_type_default.xml

However, it is still loading the file from the vendor folder. I have tried clear & flush the cache, redeploy static content, but doesn't work.

below is the change i made ( comment out the container)

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!--
/**
 * Copyright © Magento, Inc. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */
-->
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <!--<referenceContainer name="sidebar.main">
            <block class="Magento\Catalog\Block\Navigation" name="catalog.leftnav" before="-" template="Magento_Catalog::navigation/left.phtml"/>
        </referenceContainer>--> <!--remove shop by category from category listing page -->
    </body>
</page>
```

Comment: There could be 2 reasons, 1- your theme folder is in correct, ( i.e base ) move your folder to other folder which is actually being used by the theme. 2- Magento_Catalog layout is overriding by another module.

Comment: you want to remove `sidebar.main` allover website?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If `Infortis/base` is your theme name (`base` is a weird name to give to a theme and usually this is written in `CamelCase`) and you have set your theme up like [here](https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/frontend-dev-guide/themes/theme-create.html) then there are certain rules before it will show

1. Select your theme under Content > Design > Configuration > Select the right store and select `Infortis/base` there. The theme that you select there is the one that does the xml changes.
2. In your XML you need to use `referenceBlock`, `referenceContainer` or create a new block/container. More documentation [here](https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/frontend-dev-guide/layouts/xml-instructions.html)
3. In developer mode you can check your `magento_root/var/log/system.log` to check for parents that a block maybe can not find. Be sure that your log level in your `nginx` or `apache` settings are set to log all
4. You should consider load orders. More information [here](https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/extension-dev-guide/build/module-load-order.html)

**UPDATE**

Commenting out something does not remove anything. You do not 'overwrite' the XML but extend it by using it.

You can however remove something like this :

```
<referenceContainer name="name-of-the-container" remove="true"/>
<referenceBlock name="name-of-the-block" remove="true"/>
```

Comment: my theme name is Infortis/ultimo, which is the child of the infortis/base theme. I also tried to put into the Ultimo folder  in app/design/frontend/Infortis/ultimo/Magento_Catalog/layout/, but still not working. I'm only commenting out the "<referenceContainer name="sidebar.main"> ...." in the xml.  i will check through the log file. thanks

Comment: What is it exactly that you have changed in the xml?

Comment: I'm commenting out the "<referenceContainer name="sidebar.main">" container, so that the "Shop By Category" can be remove from the category view page. (Updated my question with the change i made to the xml file)

Comment: See my updated answer

Comment: that works! thanks a lot. still a lot to learn =)

Comment: do you have any ideas about this https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/264919/how-to-rename-the-product-detail-tab-title-and-display-as-the-last-tab

Answer (score 2):

Try to this way...

```
vendor/magento/module-catalog/view/frontend/layout/catalog_category_view_type_default.xml
```

to 
`app/design/frontend/Infortis/ultimo/Magento_Catalog/layout/catalog_category_view_type_default.xml`"

Or 
open this file `app/design/frontend/Infortis/ultimo/Infortis_Ultimo/layout/default.xml`

and add below code

```
<referenceBlock name="sidebar.main" remove="true"/>
```

**Please don't forget to clear cache after change in  xml files**

Comment: unfortunately, it doesn't work

Comment: i have checked my side this is working you have which mode in working ?

Comment: i'm on developer mode. should i switch to another mode?

Comment: no mate you have created file my follow path? also check which theme you are check again

Comment: yes, i created the file using the path you provided. it's pretty weird issue..