# How to rename the product detail tab title, and display as the last tab?

Tags: magento2, layout, overrides, extend

How to rename the product detail tab title, and display as the last tab?
This is what i added, but didn't make any effect.
the file is at the following location:

> /app/design/frontend/Infortis/ultimo/Amasty_Faq/layout/catalog_product_view.xml

I added:

```
<action method="setTitle">
   <argument name="title" xsi:type="string">Q&gt;A</argument>
</action>
```

and

```
<move element="amasty_faq_product_tab" destination="product.info.details" after="-" />
```

to the original xml

```
  <page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
        <head>
            <script src="Amasty_Faq::js/section/product-url.js"/>
        </head>
        <body>
            <referenceBlock name="product.info.details">
                <block class="Amasty\Faq\Block\Catalog\Product\Tab" name="amasty_faq_product_tab" ifconfig="amastyfaq/product_page/show_tab" as="amfaq_product" template="Amasty_Faq::product/questions_tab.phtml" group="detailed_info">
                    <action method="setTitle">
                        <argument name="title" xsi:type="string">Q&gt;A</argument>
                    </action>                   
                    <block class="Amasty\Faq\Block\Lists\QuestionsList" name="amasty_faq_questions" template="Amasty_Faq::lists/questions.phtml" after="-">
                        <block class="Amasty\Faq\Block\Rating\Rating" ifconfig="amastyfaq/rating/enabled" name="amasty_faq_rating" template="Amasty_Faq::rating/rating.phtml">
                            <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template" name="amasty_faq_rating_item" template="Amasty_Faq::rating/rating_item.phtml"/>
                        </block>
                        <block class="Amasty\Faq\Block\Lists\Pager" name="amasty_faq_pager"/>
                    </block>
                    <block class="Amasty\Faq\Block\Forms\AskQuestion" ifconfig="amastyfaq/product_page/show_link" name="amasty_faq_ask_question_form" template="Amasty_Faq::forms/askquestion.phtml"/>
                </block>
            </referenceBlock>
            <move element="amasty_faq_product_tab" destination="product.info.details" after="-" />
        </body>
    </page>
```

[image]

update:
I found out the tab title is set in this file. how do i override this block .php?

> /vendor/amasty/module-faq-product-questions/Block/Catalog/Product/Tab.php

I tried to extends the Tab.php by creating a module, but didnt' work

> /app/code/Kw/Renametab/Block/Catalog/Product/Tab.php

```
<?php
    /**
     * @author Amasty Team
     * @copyright Copyright (c) 2019 Amasty (https://www.amasty.com)
     * @package Amasty_Faq
     */


    namespace Kw\Renametab\Block\Catalog\Product;
    use Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template;

    class Tab extends \Amasty\Faq\Block\Catalog\Product\Tab
    {
    /**
     * Render block HTML
     *
     * @return string
     */
    protected function _toHtml()
    {
        $count = $this->getChildBlock('amasty_faq_questions')->getCollection()->count();

        $this->setTitle(__('Q&A') . (($count) ? ' (' . $count .')' : ''));

        return parent::_toHtml();
    }

}
```

> Amasty_Faq::product/questions_tab.phtml

looks like this

```
<?php
/**
 * @var \Amasty\Faq\Block\Catalog\Product\Tab $block
 */
?>
<div class="amfaq-product-tab">

    <div class="block-title">
        <!--<strong><?//= $block->escapeHtml(__('Question')); ?></strong>-->
    </div>

    <?php
    echo $block->getChildHtml('amasty_faq_questions');
    if ($block->showAskQuestionForm()) {
        echo $block->getChildHtml('amasty_faq_ask_question_form');
    }
    ?>
</div>
```

The

> /vendor/amasty/module-faq-product-questions/Block/Catalog/Product/Tab.php

looks like this, i'm not sure how to override the function, so i edit the original file for the mean time

```
<?php
/**
 * @author Amasty Team
 * @copyright Copyright (c) 2019 Amasty (https://www.amasty.com)
 * @package Amasty_Faq
 */


namespace Amasty\Faq\Block\Catalog\Product;

use Amasty\Faq\Model\ConfigProvider;
use Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template;

class Tab extends \Amasty\Faq\Block\AbstractBlock implements \Magento\Framework\DataObject\IdentityInterface
{
    /**
     * @var ConfigProvider
     */
    private $configProvider;

    /**
     * Tab constructor.
     *
     * @param Template\Context                 $context
     * @param ConfigProvider                   $configProvider
     * @param array                            $data
     */
    public function __construct(
        Template\Context $context,
        ConfigProvider $configProvider,
        array $data = []
    ) {
        parent::__construct($context, $data);
        $this->configProvider = $configProvider;
    }

    /**
     * @return int
     */
    public function getShortAnswerBehavior()
    {
        return (int)$this->configProvider->getProductPageShortAnswerBehavior();
    }

    /**
     * @return bool
     */
    public function showAskQuestionForm()
    {
        return $this->configProvider->isShowAskQuestionOnProductPage();
    }

    /**
     * Render block HTML
     *
     * @return string
     */
    protected function _toHtml()
    {
        $count = $this->getChildBlock('amasty_faq_questions')->getCollection()->count();

        $this->setTitle(__('Product Questions') . (($count) ? ' (' . $count .')' : ''));

        return parent::_toHtml();
    }

    /**
     * Return identifiers for produced content
     *
     * @return array
     */
    public function getIdentities()
    {
        return [\Amasty\Faq\Model\ResourceModel\Question\Collection::CACHE_TAG];
    }
}
```

> /app/design/frontend/Infortis/ultimo/Magento_Catalog/templates/product/view/details.phtml

look like this

```
<?php
// @codingStandardsIgnoreFile
?>
<?php
    $theme = $this->helper('Infortis\Base\Helper\Data');
    $innerContainerClasses = '';
    $jsScriptInit = '';

    $mode = $theme->getCfg('product_page/tabs');
    $openedTab = $theme->getCfg('product_page/opened_tab');
    $jsOpenedTab = '';
    if ($openedTab !== null)
    {
        $jsOpenedTab = ', "active": ' . $openedTab;
    }
    else
    {
        $jsOpenedTab = ', "active": null';
    }

    switch ($mode)
    {
        case 1:
            $innerContainerClasses = 'product data items ' . $theme->getCfg('product_page/tabs_style') . ' show-tabs';
            $jsScriptInit = '{"tabs": {"openedState": "active", "collapsible": true' . $jsOpenedTab . '}}';
            break;

        case 2:
            $innerContainerClasses = 'product data items ' . $theme->getCfg('product_page/tabs_style');
            $jsScriptInit = '{"tabs": {"openedState": "active", "collapsible": true' . $jsOpenedTab . '}}';
            break;

        default:
            $innerContainerClasses = 'product data items style1 stacked-tabs';
            $jsScriptInit = '{"tabs": {"openedState": "active", "collapsible": true}}';
            break;
    }
?>
<?php if ($detailedInfoGroup = $block->getGroupChildNames('detailed_info', 'getChildHtml')):?>

<?php//START CODE FOR LAST TAB
foreach ($detailedInfoGroup as $key => $name){
    if($name == 'amasty_faq_product_tab'){
        unset($detailedInfoGroup[$key]);
        array_push($detailedInfoGroup, $name);
    }
}// END CODE FOR LAST TAB
?>

    <div class="product info detailed collateral-container">
        <?php $layout = $block->getLayout(); ?>
        <div class="<?php echo $innerContainerClasses; ?>" <?php if ($jsScriptInit): ?>data-mage-init='<?php echo $jsScriptInit; ?>'<?php endif; ?>>
            <?php foreach ($detailedInfoGroup as $name):?>
                <?php
                    $html = $layout->renderElement($name);
                    if (!trim($html)) {
                        continue;
                    }
                    $alias = $layout->getElementAlias($name);
                    $label = $block->getChildData($alias, 'title');
                ?>
                <div class="data item title"
                    aria-labeledby="tab-label-<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $alias; ?>-title"
                    data-role="collapsible" id="tab-label-<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $alias; ?>">
                    <a class="data switch"
                        tabindex="-1"
                        data-toggle="switch"
                        href="#<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $alias; ?>"
                        id="tab-label-<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $alias; ?>-title">
                            <strong><?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $label; ?></strong>
                    </a>
                </div>
                <div class="data item content" id="<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $alias; ?>" data-role="content">
                    <?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $html; ?>
                </div>
            <?php endforeach;?>
        </div>
    </div>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: Can you provide the content of  `Amasty_Faq::product/questions_tab.phtml?` and  '/public_html/vendor/amasty/module-faq-product-questions/Block/Catalog/Product/Tab.php'

Comment: updated the question. for rename the title, i tried extend the _toHtml() function by create a module, but didn't work, so i just edit the original Tab.php in the vendor file for now.

Comment: I added my answer. Feel free to contact me if you have any further questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Overriding the original file isn't a great idea. If you once decide to update your module, all your changes would be overwritten anyway. In my opinion, this should be a setting in your adminpanel. There might be a few solutions to this.

**Change the tab title**

**Solution 1**

You can create a module and make your own Block class which extends `/vendor/amasty/module-faq-product-questions/Block/Catalog/Product/Tab.php`. Since you already did this, you just need to copy the `catalog_product_view.xml`from the Amasty_Faq module and change the original block class to yours. It should look like this:

> catalog_product_view.xml

```
  <page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceBlock name="product.info.details">
            <block class="Kw\Renametab\Block\Catalog\Product\Tab" name="amasty_faq_product_tab" ifconfig="amastyfaq/product_page/show_tab" as="amfaq_product" template="Amasty_Faq::product/questions_tab.phtml" group="detailed_info">
                <action method="setTitle">
                    <argument name="title" xsi:type="string">Q&gt;A</argument>
                </action>                   
                <block class="Amasty\Faq\Block\Lists\QuestionsList" name="amasty_faq_questions" template="Amasty_Faq::lists/questions.phtml" after="-">
                    <block class="Amasty\Faq\Block\Rating\Rating" ifconfig="amastyfaq/rating/enabled" name="amasty_faq_rating" template="Amasty_Faq::rating/rating.phtml">
                        <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template" name="amasty_faq_rating_item" template="Amasty_Faq::rating/rating_item.phtml"/>
                    </block>
                    <block class="Amasty\Faq\Block\Lists\Pager" name="amasty_faq_pager"/>
                </block>
                <block class="Amasty\Faq\Block\Forms\AskQuestion" ifconfig="amastyfaq/product_page/show_link" name="amasty_faq_ask_question_form" template="Amasty_Faq::forms/askquestion.phtml"/>
            </block>
        </referenceBlock>
        <move element="amasty_faq_product_tab" destination="product.info.details" after="-" />
    </body>
</page>
```

Also, make sure that your module depends on the Amasty_Faq module.

**Solution 2**

You can always create a preference in your di.xml, but **try to avoid this as many times as possible**. This solution should be your last and worst case scenario.

> Kw\Renametab\etc\frontend\di.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <preference for="Amasty\Faq\Block\Catalog\Product\Tab" type="Kw\Renametab\Block\Catalog\Product\Tab"/>
</config>
```

Both of these solutions should be temporary. I highly recommend you to make a request to Amasty and ask a setting for this.

**Display as the last tab**

The ideal solution would be to move the block to the end of the referenceBlock, but I tried this myself and I couldn't make it work. I did make it work by adding the follow code in `Magento_Catalog/templates/product/view/details.phtml` in your theme.

```
$detailedInfoGroup = $block->getGroupChildNames('detailed_info', 'getChildHtml');

//START CODE FOR LAST TAB
foreach ($detailedInfoGroup as $key => $name){
    if($name == 'name.of.your.block.to.display.as.last'){
        unset($detailedInfoGroup[$key]);
        array_push($detailedInfoGroup, $name);
    }
}
// END CODE FOR LAST TAB
?>
<?php if ($detailedInfoGroup):?>
    <div class="product info detailed">
           ...
    </div>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: Thanks for the in-depth answer. I'm trying these out. For it to display as the last tab, should the name.of.your.block.to.display.as.last be "amasty_faq_product_tab" in this case? doesn't seem to work for me..i added my details.phtml in the question.

Comment: Thank you. Your code works fine. I edited the wrong details.phtml file, that's why it didn't work. It's at this location app/design/frontend/Infortis/base/Infortis_Base/templates/product/view/details.phtml for my theme, instead of the app/design/frontend/Infortis/base/Magento_Catalog/templates/product/view/details.phtml

Comment: I'm glad you made it work :)

Answer (score 1):

**In catalog_product_view.xml Change This :-**

```
    <arguments>
         <argument translate="true" name="title" xsi:type="string">FAQ</argument>
         <argument name="priority" xsi:type="string">sort_order_number</argument>
    </arguments>
```

Comment: update the catalog_product_view.xml with this and clear cache, but didn't change anything. please advise.